# Is there a way to keep Zenity open after preforming my shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, zenity

I have made a zenity list that opens up the terminal to run a shell script but after it is ran zenity closes is there a way to keep zenity from closing?

Here is my script -

```
#!/bin/bash

zret="$( zenity --list --title "Tool" --list \
    --text "Select the following "for"  " \
    --checklist --column "" --column "Name" 1 \
    "PASSWORD" 2 "BOOKS" 3 "0DIMM" 4 "1DIMM" 5 "2DIMM" --width=600 --height=400 )"

if grep -qw "PEMODE PASSWORD" <<<"${zret}"; then
    
cd /home/gem/gem_rw/userpath

grep -oP '(?<=Password: ).*' file_name.dat


$SHELL
fi
```

Comment: Yep, but show your code so we can help. Describe what you need to wait for.

Comment: I just edited the post what do you think?

Comment: Can't you use python for creating your UI.

Answer (score 2):

The function of Zenity is to present a graphical dialog to request information. Once closed, it returns the information. So, no, there is no way to keep Zenity open, because it does not work that way.

You may just reopen the dialog in your shell script (e.g. by setting your shell script up as a loop, and include an option in Zenity to exit that loop, or use the exit code of Zenity to determine when to exit the loop).

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it that zenity opens terminal after I hit ok to run script. Instead of it opening terminal of rip?